# Implicit Declaration and Error Inserting a Function in XCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, function

First of all, Happy New Year to anybody out there reading this!

I have an i-phone app I am working on and wanted to make an enhancement to an IBACTION (GetNextElement) which is called from a button tap.  I wanted to call a function (get_index_to_use) rather than insert the code in GetNextElement.  When I call the function in my SymbolTest.m file, I get a warning `"implicit declaration of function get_index_to_use"`.

I get an error on the build that I don't see unless I go into Build Results where I see the following:

> Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/elements1.app/elements1 normal i386 cd
>   /Users/dad/Documents/elements1 setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
>   setenv PATH
>   "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
>   -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk
>   -L/Users/dad/Documents/elements1/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/dad/Documents/elements1/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/dad/Documents/elements1/build/elements1.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/elements1.build/Objects-normal/i386/elements1.LinkFileList
>   -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/dad/Documents/elements1/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/elements1.app/elements1
>
> Undefined symbols:   "_get_index_to_use", referenced from:
>         -[SymbolTest GetNextElement:] in SymbolTest.o ld: symbol(s) not found collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I'm not familiar with SymbolTest.o.

I have my function in the code before GetNextElement.  I tried to put it in SymbolTest.h.  I tried to put it in GetNextElement but couldn't get that to work either.  I have tried - and +.  The function looks like this (eventually I want to change how I calculate the index, but for now I am just incrementing it to get the function to work):

```
- (void)get_index_to_use {
    el_tbl_idx++;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: please post some code, i.e. the action and the declaration of get_index_to_use...

Comment: SymbolTest.o is the object file generated by the compiler, probably from SymbolTest.m (though possibly .mm or c or cpp)

Comment: Right now the get_index_to_use is a one-liner until I can get it working:

- (void)get_index_to_use {
 el_tbl_idx++;
}

It's called in an else statement:

  else {
   get_index_to_use();
   SymbolEntered.text = nil;
   ElementName.text = [NSString stringWithCString:elements_table2[el_tbl_idx].element_name];
  };

Don't know why this post isn't formatting on the display.  It looks nice in this window I am typing in but when I post it all runs together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is your problem, you have declared a method and then tried to call like a C function.

you will want to use (C style function)...

```
void get_index_to_use (void)
{ el_tbl_idx++; }
```

then call with:

```
get_index_to_use()
```

or

```
- (void) get_index_to_use
{el_tbl_idx++; }
```

and call with:

```
[self get_index_to_use];
```

or more generically:

```
[someObject get_index_to_use];
```

but it is generally a good idea to stick to naming conventions, one of which, is if you method starts with get, it should be a getter and return something. The following looks more Obj-C.

```
-(NSUInteger)getIndex {
     el_tbl_idx+=1; // or ++ or = x+1;
     return el_tbl_idx; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will give that a try.  This is my first i-phone app and I'm trying to take a c program I wrote and get it to work as an i=phone app and sometimes confuse the two.  I will try to follow the Obj-C approach.  Thanks again, and Happy New Year.

Comment: one thing to note... all C is valid in Objective-C.. no need to reinvent the wheel... the only thing you will really have to remember is that any objects iVars are only available in the objects (instance) methods. Calling a C function is a little bit faster than calling a method.